# How to resolve the fatal error "Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /xyz/pqr/prj_name/functions/common.php on line 865"?

Tags: php, date, datetime, format, fatal-error

Following is the necessary code from file "`/xyz/pqr/prj_name/functions/common.php`"

```
function format_date_yyyy_mm_dd($date_val) {
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('n-j-Y', $date_val);
  return $date->format('Y-m-d');  //Thie is line no.865 where I'm getting the error.
}
```

This file has been included into the file where the function `format_date_yyyy_mm_dd()` is called.

The code for calling the function is as follows :

```
$form_data['reg_date'] = format_date_yyyy_mm_dd($form_data['reg_date']);
```

Can some one please help in correcting the code I've written and help me where my code is going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a `print_r()` on `$date`? `print_r($date); exit();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is correct, please check the value of `$form_data['reg_date']` and make sure it is something like `12-19-2014` and it should be `month-date-year`. You may passing wrong format of date from your form.

```
echo format_date_yyyy_mm_dd('12-19-2014');
```